# Как сделать страницу пользователя с данными и циклом

Tags: laravel

На странице должно быть три типа переменных.

Данные должны выдаваться из адресной строки браузера по url:

```
userfotos/1 Мои данные Auth Guest Данные users Цикл fotos
```

У меня конфликт с ними

Comment: ? ты имеешь ввиду `auth()->user->fotos` ? и с чем у тебя конфликт, уточни, ты настроил связь в модели User и фото

Comment: ты ж понимаешь что return из функции может быть только один ? а у тебя их 2 минимум ) ты должен сделать выборку а потом return view('userfots')->with(['users'=>$users, 'photos'=>$photos]);

Comment: Приведите полный код контроллера и вьюхи, в самом описании, не в коментах только

Comment: Какой то у вас гениальнейший бред :( Вы часто видели несколько body в документе ?

Comment: очисти шаблон свой и сделай внутри вот так `@php dd(users,files) @endphp`

Comment: опечатался $users,$files

Comment: Я же тебе сказал выше, не бывает несколько body в одном документе поэтому твой цикл отображает только первую итерацию

Comment: Боди это не просто тэг читай мат часть, что такое html документ, по тому, что ты делаешь я вообще не пойму что у тебя должно происходить, если ты хочешь, что б для разных юзеров было разное отображение то, тебе нужно просто сделать проверку, а не делать цикл

Comment: Какую проверку ? Напиши код